# How to send trace ID through kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth

Microservice1 -> kafka -> Microservice2
How do I pass the trace ID when transferring data?
and i'm using spring sleuth for makeing trace ID.
and i'm using "compile('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.1.2.RELEASE')"

Comment: it is about configuring kafka to send to zipkin. My question is how to send trace ID when service1 -> kafka -> service2 configuration.

Comment: [This page](https://github.com/WhiteLagoon/sample-cloud-stream-with-kafka-with-sleuth) is exactly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_sleuth_with_zipkin_over_rabbitmq_or_kafka

> 48.3.3 Sleuth with Zipkin over RabbitMQ or Kafka If you want to use RabbitMQ or Kafka instead of HTTP, add the spring-rabbit or
>   spring-kafka dependency. The default destination name is zipkin.
>
> If using Kafka, you must set the property spring.zipkin.sender.type
>   property accordingly:
>
> spring.zipkin.sender.type: kafka [Caution]    Caution
>   spring-cloud-sleuth-stream is deprecated and incompatible with these
>   destinations.
>
> If you want Sleuth over RabbitMQ, add the spring-cloud-starter-zipkin
>   and spring-rabbit dependencies.
>
> The following example shows how to do so for Gradle:
>
> Maven.

```
<dependencyManagement> 1
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
               <version>${release.train.version}</version>
               <type>pom</type>
               <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies> </dependencyManagement>

 <dependency> 2
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId> </dependency> <dependency> 3
     <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId> </dependency> 1
```

> We recommend that you add the dependency management through the Spring
>   BOM so that you need not manage versions yourself.
>
> 2
>
> Add the dependency to spring-cloud-starter-zipkin. That way, all
>   nested dependencies get downloaded.
>
> 3
>
> To automatically configure RabbitMQ, add the spring-rabbit dependency.
>
> Gradle.

```
dependencyManagement { 1
     imports {
         mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${releaseTrainVersion}"
     } }

 dependencies {
     compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin" 2
     compile "org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit" 3 } 1
```

> We recommend that you add the dependency management through the Spring
>   BOM so that you need not manage versions yourself.
>
> 2
>
> Add the dependency to spring-cloud-starter-zipkin. That way, all
>   nested dependencies get downloaded.
>
> 3
>
> To automatically configure RabbitMQ, add the spring-rabbit dependency.

Comment: This is about configuring kafka to send to zipkin.
My question is how to send trace ID when service1 -> kafka -> service2 configuration.

Comment: User spring cloud stream

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? Perhaps showing code would be better than copying the docs verbatim? Specifically, you should remove the RabbitMQ references

Comment: Yes, I wrote the library and I wrote those docs too so I did check this myself. This is an example for rabbit but you can use a kafka related dependency.